# Java split xml string containing multiple xml files while keeping the pattern

Tags: java, xml, string, split

I am currently working with a XML string (all xml data stored in String xml) that is made of multiple XML files in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File xml:space="preserve">
     <Subfile keyword="Store" tag="0">
          <Value number="1">Amazon</Value>
     </Subfile>
     <Subfile keyword="Owner" tag="1">
          <Value number="1">Alice Murphy</Value>
     </Subfile>
     <Subfile keyword="Date" tag="2">
          <Value number="1">20161114</Value>
     </Subfile>
</File>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File xml:space="preserve">
     <Subfile keyword="Store" tag="0">
          <Value number="1">Walmart</Value>
     </Subfile>
     <Subfile keyword="Owner" tag="1">
          <Value number="1">Eliza Calvin</Value>
     </Subfile>
     <Subfile keyword="Date" tag="2">
          <Value number="1">20161130</Value>
     </Subfile>
</File>
...
```

I want to split this xml string by using String.split() based on the xml tag.

I also want the resulting elements of the array to retain the xml tag that is acting as the delimiter.

The code I used was

```
String[] xmls = xmlString.split("(?=<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>)");
```

However, nothing happened when I did this.  What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're not escaping special characters.

Comment: Also, *nothing happened* is not a very useful problem description.

Comment: Use `Pattern.quote()` to escape the pattern

Answer (score 2):

You just need to escape the `?` character by adding `\\` before it. It happens for all special characters that have some meaning in a regex. So you need to have `\\` as a prefix whenever you want to use the special characters as simple string characters.

The following code snippet works.

```
String separator = "(?=<\\?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"\\?>)";
String[] xmls = xmlString.split(separator);
for (String xml : xmls) {
    System.out.println(xml);
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
}
```

It prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File xml:space="preserve">
     <Subfile keyword="Store" tag="0">
          <Value number="1">Amazon</Value>
     </Subfile>
     <Subfile keyword="Owner" tag="1">
          <Value number="1">Alice Murphy</Value>
     </Subfile>
     <Subfile keyword="Date" tag="2">
          <Value number="1">20161114</Value>
     </Subfile>
</File>


-----------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File xml:space="preserve">
     <Subfile keyword="Store" tag="0">
          <Value number="1">Walmart</Value>
     </Subfile>
     <Subfile keyword="Owner" tag="1">
          <Value number="1">Eliza Calvin</Value>
     </Subfile>
     <Subfile keyword="Date" tag="2">
          <Value number="1">20161130</Value>
     </Subfile>
</File>
-----------------------------------
```

**Edit**: `.` should be escaped as follows.

```
String separator = "(?=<\\?xml version=\"1\\.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"\\?>)";
```

Thanks to @shmosel for pointing out this.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Glad to learn that "?" requires "//" in this case. Thank you.

Comment: The `.` needs to be escaped as well.

Comment: @shmosel you are right, `.` is also a special character. perhaps my code is working because `.` is in between quotation sign! not sure though.

Comment: It's working because `.` matches any character, including `.`.

Comment: it's always troubling seeing regular expressions being used on XML. Granted, this is not a valid XML file.
Just be aware that any CDATA section within the XML can potentially make this fail, i.e.
<![CDATA[
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    ]]>

Highly unlikely, but not unheard of ;)